# How to add core data to my exisiting iOS project in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Core Data to existing iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project)

In my existing iOS project in xcode, there is no core data.

I need to add core data back to the project, how to do that ?

Thanks.