# migrate my project to use Core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

i have developed an ios application (not finished), and know i would like to migrate my project to use core Data, it's this possible ? if yes How ?

Comment: Look for example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959720/how-to-add-core-data-to-my-exisiting-ios-project-in-xcode

Comment: [This might help](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without giving any specifics it is difficult to be specific in an answer.
What you need to do is to link to the binary of the CoreData Framework in your solution.
You need to decide which storage you wish to use (sqlite etc). Is the information to be persisted user preferences? Is is a mini database? Is is one flat file store?
At the end of the day you'll need to do some reading based on which of the types of backing store you choose.

Hope this helps as a starting point.